# Releasing memory allocated by C-runtime from Haskell

Tags: c, haskell, garbage-collection

I am learning how to use Haskell's C FFI.

Suppose I am calling a C-function which creates an object and then returns a pointer to that object. Am I allowed to free this memory from the Haskell run-time using `free`? 
(I am referring to Haskell's`free` **not** C's `free`)

Consider the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Main where
import Prelude hiding (exp)
import Foreign.Marshal.Alloc
import Foreign.Storable
import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign.Ptr 
import Foreign.Marshal.Array

foreign import ccall "get_non_freed_array"  c_get_non_freed_array :: CInt -> IO (Ptr CInt) -- An array initialized

main :: IO()
main = do
  let numelements = 5
  ptr <-  c_get_non_freed_array  numelements
  w0  <-  peek $ advancePtr ptr 0 
  w1  <-  peek $ advancePtr ptr 1 
  w2  <-  peek $ advancePtr ptr 2 
  w3  <-  peek $ advancePtr ptr 3 
  w4  <-  peek $ advancePtr ptr 4 
  print [w0, w1, w2, w3, w4]
  return ()
```

The `get_non_freed_array` function I have written in C99 is as follows

```
#include "test.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
// return a memory block that is not freed.
int* get_non_freed_array(int n)
{
  int* ptr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

  for(int i=0 ; i<n ; ++i){
          ptr[i] = i*i;
   }
  return ptr;
}
```

(`test.h` just contains a single line containing the function signature of `get_non_freed_array` for Haskell's FFI to access it.)

I am confused because I don't know whether the memory allocated by the C-runtime is garbage collected when that C function "finishes" running after being called from Haskell's run-time. I mean, if it were another *C* function calling it, then I know the memory would be safe to use, but since a Haskell function is calling `get_non_freed_array`, I don't know if this is true anymore.

Even though the above Haskell code prints correct results, I don't know if the memory returned by the C-function is safe to use via `ptr`.

If it is safe, can we free this memory from Haskell itself? Or do I have to write another C-function, say, `destroy_array(int* ptr)` inside test.c and then call it from Haskell?

---

**Edit:** In short, I need more information on how to work with pointers to objects created inside C-functions when writing code in Haskell.

Comment: Which Haskell `free` are you referring to? Do you have a docs reference? Etit: NVM, it's http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1-rc2/docs/html/libraries/base-4.9.0.0/Foreign-Marshal-Alloc.html#v:free

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Alloc.html#v:free

Comment: I would guess that it won't be safe, as the allocation algorithm might be different for C and Haskell. But you can try, and if you are lucky you will get some segmentation fault to know you can't do this.

Comment: You should only ever use the free that matches the allocator user to allocate the memory.  This applies even without crossing language barriers.   Different libraries in C can use different allocators.  You need to use the correct free function for everything.

Comment: To answer your last question (the one with `destroy_array`): That is one safe solution, yes. Another would be to do the allocation in Haskell using [`alloca`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Foreign-Marshal-Array.html#v:allocaArray) (or `mallocArray` if you don't want the memory to be managed by GHC) and pass a pointer to the allocated memory to your C function (freeing it from Haskell afterwards in the `mallocArray` case; in the `allocaArray` case you won't need to do anything more). I often find this approach tidier than allocating/freeing on the C side.

Comment: @gspr I see. So in a nutshell, I should manage both allocation and deallocation only on either Haskell's or C's side, right?

Comment: @smilingbuddha: Yup. And at least in my experience, it tends to be a lot nicer and cleaner to do it on the Haskell side. `alloca` and friends + the [C types](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Foreign-C-Types.html#t:CInt) are nice. Once you get into having to generate a bunch of Haskell versions of more complicated C types (for allocation purposes), I find that the [bindings-DSL](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bindings-DSL) package can help a lot (while being *very* simple and magic-free in its use).

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** Deallocate memory with the correct corresponding function (e.g. C's `malloc` with C's `free`), and prefer `alloca`-style functions or `ForeignPtr` if that's not possible.

---

A `Ptr` is just an address. An [`Addr#`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1-rc2/docs/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.5.0.0/GHC-Prim.html#t:Addr-35-) usually points outside of the garbage collected machinery. With this knowledge, we can answer your first implicit question: no, the memory allocated by the C-runtime won't get garbage collected when the C function finishes.

Next, it isn't safe *in general* to free the memory from Haskell itself. You've used C's `malloc`, so you should use C's `free`. While the current implementation of Haskell's `free` uses C's, you cannot count on that, as  [`Foreign.Marshal.Alloc.free`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1-rc2/docs/html/libraries/base-4.9.0.0/Foreign-Marshal-Alloc.html#v:free) is meant for the Haskell variants.

Note that I said *in general*. The current implementation in GHC uses just the C counterparts, but one should not count on that and instead use the corresponding function. This corresponds to your `destroy_array` approach: Lucky for us, that's not hard:

```
foreign import ccall "stdlib.h free" c_free :: Ptr CInt -> IO ()
```

Your C documentation should include a remark that `free` is the correct function though. Now, you *could* write your `main` like this:

```
main :: IO()
main = do
  let numelements = 5
  ptr <-  c_get_non_freed_array  numelements
  w0  <-  peek $ advancePtr ptr 0 
  w1  <-  peek $ advancePtr ptr 1 
  w2  <-  peek $ advancePtr ptr 2 
  w3  <-  peek $ advancePtr ptr 3 
  w4  <-  peek $ advancePtr ptr 4 
  print [w0, w1, w2, w3, w4]
  c_free ptr
  return ()
```

But that's just as error prone as in C. You've asked for garbage collection. That's what a [`ForeignPtr`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.0.1-rc2/docs/html/libraries/base-4.9.0.0/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html#v:ForeignPtr) is for. We can create one from a normal `Ptr`  with `newForeignPtr`:

```
newForeignPtr :: FinalizerPtr a -> Ptr a -> IO (ForeignPtr a)
```

Source
The `FinalizerPtr` (`type FinalizerPtr a = FunPtr (Ptr a -> IO ())` is a function pointer. So we need to adjust our previous import slightly:

```
--                                    v
foreign import ccall unsafe "stdlib.h &free" c_free_ptr :: FinalizerPtr CInt
--                                    ^
```

Now we can create your array:

```
makeArray :: Int -> ForeignPtr CInt
makeArray n = c_get_non_freed_array >>= newForeignPtr c_free_ptr
```

In order to actually work with the `ForeignPtr`, we need to use `withForeignPtr`:

```
main :: IO()
main = do
  let numelements = 5
  fptr <-  makeArray  numelements
  withForeignPtr fptr $ \ptr -> do
      w0  <-  peek $ advancePtr ptr 0 
      w1  <-  peek $ advancePtr ptr 1 
      w2  <-  peek $ advancePtr ptr 2 
      w3  <-  peek $ advancePtr ptr 3 
      w4  <-  peek $ advancePtr ptr 4 
      print [w0, w1, w2, w3, w4]
  return ()
```

The difference between `Ptr` and `ForeignPtr` is that the latter will call a finalizer. But this example is slightly contrived. The `alloca*` functions make your life a lot easier if you just want to allocate something, work with a function on it, and then return, e.g.

```
withArrayLen xs $ \n ptr -> do
   c_fast_sort n ptr
   peekArray n ptr
```

The `Foreign.Marshal.*` modules have many useful functions for that.

**Final remark:** working with raw memory can be a nuisance and an error source. Hide it if you make a library for public use.